# Google Sheets - index importxml doesn't work

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I wanted to make a sheet with information about companies, but unfortunately, impossible to do so.

However, I don't know what else I can do, I followed the instructions in the documentation to the letter:

- I have the URL : https://www.stockopedia.com/share-prices/EPA:GET/
- I have the XPath of the element I want:
  [image]

(I even made two versions, one with " " and another with ' '), or with the "full XPath" and nothing works, I don't see what else I can do...

- `//*[@id="__next"]/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/dd[1]/a`
- `//*[@id='__next']/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/dd[1]/a`
- `/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/dd[2]/a`

[image]

Can you help me ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You will use the single quotes within the double quotes.

I had success with

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.stockopedia.com/share-prices/EPA:GET/","//*[@id='__next']/main/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/dd[1]/a")
```

[Example sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sxgihjU4b-Oqfr4oBQCywJHIXG_J7DbCnLVdYt3w33U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much Tom. I think I'll use yours so...
Because mine is still loading... https://postimg.cc/tYvntdnL
Maybe because it's an .XLSX ? mh I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=index(importxml(url,"//a[@class='stk-breadcrumbs__link']"),2)
```

[image]